# Redirect NON-www to www for https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, http-redirect, no-www

I've the following redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How can I redirect non WWW https to WWW?

The htaccess is located in the public_html folder

Comment: did you find the answer to this - the answers in the thread are all missing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect

- http://example.com
- https://example.com

to

- https://www.example.com

Comment: This is a tested rule and it works fine on my server.  clear your browser cache

Comment: Works :D I've put the htaccess in the top root where are located the public_html, private_html folders etc. Thanks @starkeen

Comment: Even works http:// www . example . com to https:// www . example . com - Thank you @starkeen

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this on a Joomla site and it redirects everything to https://www
I can't see this solution anywhere else so thought I'd share it

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm for a Joomla! website. Thanks