# How Redirect Website URL to HTTPS:// using .HTACCESS File

Tags: .htaccess

I am using .htaccess file to redirect my webpage URL to https://. But this code redirects only www.domain-name. If we type just https://domain-name.in or domain-name it is not redirecting. Please help me to solve this issue and redirect all URL to https://

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.in$
RewriteRule ^$ https://domainname.in/%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Please do use proper tagging: this question is in no way related to PHP or HTML5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect NON-www to www for https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241057/redirect-non-www-to-www-for-https)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```